# How does the trace map affect modular forms modulo $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Suppose $M,N \geq 1$ are positive integers and consider the trace map
$$\text{Tr}: M_2(\Gamma_1(MN)) \to M_2(\Gamma_1(N)).$$
Say we have a modular form $f = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nq^n \in M_2(\Gamma_1(MN))$. We will also put $\text{Tr}(f) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nq^n \in M_2(\Gamma_1(N))$. Suppose further that the coefficients of $f$ and $\text{Tr}(f)$ are in $\mathbf{Z}$.

Let $p$ be an odd prime which does not divide $N$. *My question is:* does $\text{Tr}(f) \equiv 0$ modulo $p$ imply that $f \equiv 0$ modulo $p$? That is, do we have the implication
$$b_n \equiv 0 \pmod p \text{ for all }n \implies a_n \equiv 0 \pmod p \text{ for all }n?$$

Comment: Obviously not: if $f$ is a newform then $Tr(f) = 0$ but its mod $p$ reduction will be non-zero.

Comment: I see, thanks. Why does a newform have trace equal to zero?

Comment: By definition if $f$ is new at level $MN$, then $f$ is orthogonal to $i(g)$ for every $g$ at level $N$, where $i$ is the obvious inclusion of $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ in $S_k(\Gamma_1(MN))$. Since we have $\langle f, i(g) \rangle = \langle Tr(f), g \rangle$ up to a nonzero scalar (see e.g. Diamond + Shurman ex 5.4.4), it follows that $Tr(f) \in S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ is orthogonal to everything, and since the Petersson product is positive definite, this means it must be zero.